# Wait for a page response and measure time taken in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Our IBM Filenet application has user inboxes which handle various workflows.
for example, user kickso off the proces of copying a case (document or file) -> case gets copied in background by process engine -> the 'copy succes' message appears in the user inbox.

How can I tell JMeter to look for a specific response in the body, and measure the time taken for this specific response to be shown? the idea is to measure how long the content engine takes for copying a case (can by anything, mostly large collections of documents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such case the best option is to use browser automation. There is [Selenium/WebDriver plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSet/) for JMeter. Then you can add to your scenario *jp@gc - Web Driver Sampler* with following, quite self-explaining code:

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium, org.openqa.selenium.support.ui)
var wait = new pkg.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 10)

WDS.browser.get('http://yourhost/yourpath')
wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.id('btnToBePressed')))

var button = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('btnToBePressed'));
button.click();

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.cssSelector('.ShowResultsTobeWaited')));
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

Of course you can create much more complicated scenarios with this. It depends on your needs.

Comment: We do not consider to measure this way anymore. Reason is, that the IBM FileNet proces engine contains loggers which actually have information about start/end time of specific content operations. I will extract these numbers over a set of X amount of operations, and calculate averages.